# An apply that doesn't seem like it should unify is allowed

Tags: coq, unification

I'm running into what I believe could be a bug in Coq 8.4pl5. Given this proof state:

```
1 subgoal

st : state
a : sinstr
a0 : list sinstr
b : list sinstr
IHa : forall stack : list nat,
      s_execute st stack (a0 ++ b) = s_execute st (s_execute st stack a0) b
stack : list nat

======================== ( 1 / 1 )
s_execute st stack ((a :: a0) ++ b) =
s_execute st (s_execute st stack (a :: a0)) b
```

Coq is allowing me to `apply IHa`. When I do this, it discharges the goal and proves the theorem.

Is this an incorrect unification (I'm thinking that it is) and, if so, has this issue been reported yet?

If not, how would I go about reporting it? I know that Coq is used in high assurance software and I believe that, even though this isn't the latest version, it isn't a particularly old version. So, even if it is fixed in later versions, it would be good to make sure people are aware that this issue does exist in this version of Coq.

For reference, I have narrowed the code down to this (I haven't tried to narrow it down further because I don't fully understand what might be causing this). The `apply` in question is in the second to last line (with all the asterisks in a comment):

```
(** aexp **)
Require Import Coq.Arith.Peano_dec.

Inductive id : Type :=
| Id : nat -> id.

Theorem eq_id_dec : forall a b : id,
  {a = b} + {a <> b}.
Proof.
  intros.
  case_eq a.
  case_eq b.
  intros.
  destruct (eq_nat_dec n0 n).
    left. auto.
    right. unfold not. intros. inversion H1. contradiction.
Qed.


Definition state : Type := id -> nat.

Definition empty_state : state :=
  fun _ => 0.

Definition update (st : state) (i : id) (v : nat) : state :=
  fun j => if eq_id_dec j i
            then v
            else st j.

Inductive aexp : Type :=
  | AId : id -> aexp
  | ANum : nat -> aexp
  | APlus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
  | AMinus : aexp -> aexp -> aexp
  | AMult : aexp -> aexp -> aexp.

Fixpoint aeval (a : aexp) (st : state) : nat :=
  match a with
  | AId i => st i
  | ANum n => n
  | APlus x y => aeval x st + aeval y st
  | AMinus x y => aeval x st - aeval y st
  | AMult x y => aeval x st * aeval y st
  end.

(** Stack compiler **)

Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.


Inductive sinstr : Type :=
| SPush : nat -> sinstr
| SLoad : id -> sinstr
| SPlus : sinstr
| SMinus : sinstr
| SMult : sinstr.

Fixpoint s_execute (st : state) (stack : list nat) (prog : list sinstr)
    : list nat :=
  match prog with
  | nil => stack
  | cons x xs =>
      let stack' := match x with
      | SPush a => cons a stack
      | SLoad v => cons (st v) stack
      | SPlus   => match stack with
                   | cons a (cons b rest) => cons (b + a) rest
                   | _ => [27]
                   end
      | SMinus  => match stack with
                   | cons a (cons b rest) => cons (b - a) rest
                   | _ => [27]
                   end
      | SMult   => match stack with
                   | cons a (cons b rest) => cons (b * a) rest
                   | _ => [27]
                   end
      end
      in
      s_execute st stack' xs
  end.


Fixpoint s_compile (e : aexp) : list sinstr :=
  match e with
  | AId i => [ SLoad i ]
  | ANum n => [ SPush n ]
  | APlus a b => (s_compile a) ++ (s_compile b) ++ [ SPlus ]
  | AMinus a b => (s_compile a) ++ (s_compile b) ++ [ SMinus ]
  | AMult a b => (s_compile a) ++ (s_compile b) ++ [ SMult ]
  end.

Lemma s_execute_app : forall st stack a b,
  s_execute st stack (a ++ b) = s_execute st (s_execute st stack a) b.
Proof.
  intros.
  generalize dependent stack.
  induction a ; try reflexivity.
    intros.
    apply IHa. (***********************)
Qed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `simpl` after introducing, you'll see that the hypothesis and the goal *can* unify:

```
 s_execute st
     match a with
     | SPush a1 => a1 :: stack
     | SLoad v => st v :: stack
     | SPlus =>
         match stack with
         | [] => [27]
         | [a1] => [27]
         | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 + a1 :: rest
         end
     | SMinus =>
         match stack with
         | [] => [27]
         | [a1] => [27]
         | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 - a1 :: rest
         end
     | SMult =>
         match stack with
         | [] => [27]
         | [a1] => [27]
         | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 * a1 :: rest
         end
     end (a0 ++ b) =
   s_execute st
     (s_execute st
        match a with
        | SPush a1 => a1 :: stack
        | SLoad v => st v :: stack
        | SPlus =>
            match stack with
            | [] => [27]
            | [a1] => [27]
            | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 + a1 :: rest
            end
        | SMinus =>
            match stack with
            | [] => [27]
            | [a1] => [27]
            | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 - a1 :: rest
            end
        | SMult =>
            match stack with
            | [] => [27]
            | [a1] => [27]
            | a1 :: b0 :: rest => b0 * a1 :: rest
            end
        end a0) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you might not want to report this particular issue, thanks to Arthur's analysis, if you want to contact Coq developers, they hang out on the Coq-club and Coq-dev mailing lists.  See

https://coq.inria.fr/community

for archives and more info.
There is also a bug tracking system, Coq-bugs, that you can use.